# Trying to remove quotation marks and dashes when using the REGEXREPLACE formula in GOOGLE SHEETS. I am still really new at this so bear with me

Tags: google-sheets, replace, regexp-replace

I am trying to remove any quotation marks and dashes and replace them with a space in Column D. I have an existing formula for REGEXREPLACE that is copying over everything from Column C. I am wanting to keep that the same while at the same time removing the quotation marks and dashes in Column D when everything is copied over. I think another formula is going to have be written into my existing one but not entirely sure.

Forumula: =regexreplace(C3:C40001,"([^()]*)","")

I tried to use the SUBSTITUTE and REGEXP_REPLACE formula within the REGEXREPLACE formula but kept getting an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pxCx.jpg)

Comment: You need to provide the input and the desired output, so people understand better your situation. Even better, you can share a spreadsheet with some example, showing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: use this formula to trim spaces and parenthesis

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(C3:C400,"\-|\'|\,|\(|\)|\"""," ")))
```

You could use something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(C3:C40000,"-|'|\"""," "))
```

This replaced - ' and " you can also add more characters by adding this symbol: |

If it is a special character from Regex you should preceed it with this slash \

Comment: That did work! But I did notice some Parentheses that were in some rows and I tried this string based =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(C3:C40000,"-|'|,|()|,\"""," "))
 off what you said, but it just put a space in between each letter and not removing the Parentheses.

Comment: Try separating your () with this symbol | like this (|)

Comment: Ok yes that did resolve the spacing issue but still shows the Parentheses. i.e
:NELL   (BETH)

Comment: It was what I said in the post earlier. Parenthesis are special characters in REGEX, add this slash \

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(C3:C40000,"-|'|,|()|,\""|\(|\)"," "))

Comment: And finally, to suppress double spaces: =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(C3:C40000,"-|'|,|()|,\""|(|)"," ")))

Comment: It did reduce the spacing on a few things but I am still seeing the spaces between each letter and the parentheses. I will add a screenshot of what I am seeing. I linked the image in the original post at the top.

Comment: Could you please copy exactly your formula as it is now??

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(C3:C40000,"-|'|,|(|),\""|(|)"," ")))

Comment: Just found it, I mixed two formulas when translating the formula to English  =ARRAYFORMULA(SUPPRESPACE(REGEXREPLACE(C3:C40000,"-|'|,|\(|\)|\"""," ")))

Comment: I see that TRIM is Equivalent to SUPPRESPACE in English. But for some reason, I am still getting the same results with the spacing and parentheses as in the linked image above.

Comment: I'll edit the post, it's suppressing some characters in the comments

Comment: In the post it's seen as it should be... the comments kept deleting the reversed slashes

Comment: This is what I have =ARRAYFORMULA(SUPPRESPACE(REGEXREPLACE(C3:C40000,"-|'|,|(|)|\"""," ")))
 
But even still I see spaces between each letter and the parentheses are still there

Comment: See it in my spreadsheet, in the comments the formula is cut: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vIAQcPHhjX3_OZjwETabIbAvty6_Y89Ksvk8RSqnSs0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: YEP That worked! Finally! WOW

Comment: Thank you so much, Martín! You were a huge help is solving this.I am very thankful for your help sir.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I'm sorry that the comment section gave us a little headache, he. You should close the question ;)